# Why am I getting the response "SecretHash does not match for the client" during AWS Congito User confirmation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, awscognitotoken

I'm getting the following response during user confirmation with AWS Cognito:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "SecretHash does not match for the client: [REDACTED] (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: [REDACTED]; Proxy: null)",
  "errorType": "com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.NotAuthorizedException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811)",
    "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395)",
    "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)",
    "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)",
    "com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)",
...
```

I'm using the implementation [recommended by AWS for user signup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/example_cognito-identity-provider_SignUp_section.html):

```
public static void signUp(CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient, String clientId, String userName, String password, String email) {
    AttributeType userAttrs = AttributeType.builder()
        .name("email")
        .value(email)
        .build();

    List<AttributeType> userAttrsList = new ArrayList<>();
    userAttrsList.add(userAttrs);
    try {
        SignUpRequest signUpRequest = SignUpRequest.builder()
            .userAttributes(userAttrsList)
            .username(userName)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .password(password)
            .withSecretHash(calculateSecretHash(clientId, USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET, userName))
            .build();

        identityProviderClient.signUp(signUpRequest);
        System.out.println("User has been signed up ");

    } catch(CognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

I'm using the implementation [recommended by AWS for user confirmation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/example_cognito-identity-provider_ConfirmSignUp_section.html) (with the `withSecretHash()` method added):

```
public static void confirmSignUp(CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient, String clientId, String code, String userName) {
    try {
        ConfirmSignUpRequest signUpRequest = ConfirmSignUpRequest.builder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .confirmationCode(code)
            .username(userName)
            .withSecretHash(calculateSecretHash(clientId, USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET, userName))
            .build();

        identityProviderClient.confirmSignUp(signUpRequest);
        System.out.println(userName + " was confirmed");

    } catch(CognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

I'm using the implementation [recommended by AWS for calculating the hash](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#cognito-user-pools-computing-secret-hash):

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
 
public static String calculateSecretHash(String userPoolClientId, String userPoolClientSecret, String userName) {
    final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";
    
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
            userPoolClientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
            HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        mac.update(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(userPoolClientId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawHmac);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while calculating ");
    }
}
```

Additional points which I don't know that matter or not:

1. I'm using the following Authentication flows:

- ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
- ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH

2. I'm using the correct username and confirmation code sent via email.

Can anyone point out where I may be going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Tried to sign a user up and confirm them using the Java AWS SDK.
Expected to be able to sign them up and confirm them.
Resulted in error: "errorMessage": "SecretHash does not match for the client: [REDACTED] (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: [REDACTED]; Proxy: null)",

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few different things but eventually realized that I had some trailing whitespace where I was setting the environment variables in my lambda. I cleaned that up and it was working.